# Pandas: Inconsistent Behavior of File Encoding Specification Across Different Machines

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have a CSV file with 4 columns, and here is a selection of rows:

```
San José State,[San José State](#f/sanjosestate),San Jose State,San Jose St.
```

Note the `é` characters in the second line. I want to read this DataFrame into Pandas, which I have done like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/team_list.csv', names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'], index_col = 0)
df.iloc[254:257]
```

```
San Francisco    [San Francisco](#f/sanfrancisco)   San Francisco  San Francisco
San José State  [San José State](#f/sanjosestate)  San Jose State   San Jose St.
Santa Clara          [Santa Clara](#f/santaclara)     Santa Clara    Santa Clara
```

Note that the `é` character is accurately represented. I ran this on a Mac machine, with Python version 3.7.0 and pandas version 1.1.5.

However, when I run the same lines of code on the same file but on a Linux Raspberry Pi machine (Python 3.7.3, pandas 1.1.5), I get the following output:

```
San Francisco    [San Francisco](#f/sanfrancisco)   San Francisco  San Francisco
San Jos? State  [San Jos? State](#f/sanjosestate)  San Jose State   San Jose St.
Santa Clara          [Santa Clara](#f/santaclara)     Santa Clara    Santa Clara
```

Note that the `é` is now represented by a question mark. Following the advice of many similar threads on this forum, I specified the encoding as UTF-8 by importing with:

```
pd.read_csv('data/team_list.csv', names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'], encoding = 'utf-8', index_col = 0)
```

However, this did not change the behavior on either machine—on my MacBook, the character appears properly, and on the Raspberry Pi, it does not. I also tried importing with latin-1 encoding:

```
pd.read_csv('data/team_list.csv', names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'], encoding = 'latin-1', index_col = 0)
```

Now, the behavior has flipped. On my Raspberry Pi, the character loads correctly, but on my MacBook, I see:

```
San JosÃ© State  [San JosÃ© State](#f/sanjosestate)  San Jose State   San Jose St.
```

In all cases, it is more than just a rendering issue as if I try to run a line of code, say `df.loc['San José State']`, I get an error that `'San José State'` is not in the index in the cases where the data isn't imported properly.

I can not find a single encoding that "works" on both my MacBook and my Raspberry Pi, which is very frustrating.

I have run `file -I data/team_list.csv` on my Mac, which returned `data/team_list.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8`. `file -i data/team_list.csv` on my RPi returned the same, indicating that both operating systems are recognizing the file as UTF-8.

Why then, do I see this inconsistent behavior? If I explicitly tell pandas the encoding is UTF-8, why does the character load properly on one platform but not on the other? Is there any fix for this?

Comment: All indications are that the file is encoded in ISO-8859-1 (latin1) on the Raspberry Pi, and UTF-8 on the Mac.  Are you *sure* the two files are identical because evidence says they are not.  UTF-8 read as latin-1 appears exactly as your final example on the Macbook.  The one odd things is `pandas.read_csv` docs say the default *encoding_errors* is `'strict'` and should raise an exception on latin-1 read as UTF-8, but that is 1.4.3 docs.  1.1.5 docs doesn't have that parameter so may be using `'replace'` internally.

Comment: I `scp`ed the file between the machines so there is nothing that would suggest the files are different. I also verified that the SHA-256 checksums are the same as well. I don't see an `encoding_errors` parameter in the `read_csv` docs in 1.1.5 so maybe you are on to something. But that would still not explain the difference in behavior

Comment: One more hypothesis to check: the files are read correctly on both machines, but the mismatch happens when you print the contents or access them through typing in column keys in an interpreter session. A way to check safely is the `ascii()` function, which is like `repr` but escapes all non-ASCII characters. If you see `'Jos\\xe9'`, loading was correct; `'Jos\\xc3\\xa9'` is the garbled version.

Comment: Apologies for being late to this, but I do see the garbled version when running `ascii(teams.index[255])`, which is not surprising as equality checks for San José State fail. However,  when running `ascii` when the name renders with a question mark, I see `Jos\\xe9`. Interesting, I will follow up once I figure out more!